# RestAssured authentication with AWS Signature

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest-assured, amazon-cognito

I would to know how to pass an AWS authentication signature to RestAssured. AWS Signature authentication doesn't seem to be built into RestAssured. Any help on how to get it to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was a lot more complicated than I would have hoped for.

I found a link that provides the code to so the signing portion https://www.javaquery.com/2016/01/aws-version-4-signing-process-complete.html

In my case, I had to provide the session token as well so I had to add that information in the signer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "xxxxx-yyyyy-r6nvlhpscgdwms5.ap-northeast-1.es.amazonaws.com/inventory/simple/123";

    RequestSpecification restAssuredRequest;
    restAssuredRequest = RestAssured.given();

    JSONObject restAssuredRequestParams = new JSONObject();
    restAssuredRequestParams.put("AccessToken", accessToken);
    restAssuredRequestParams.put("YourParam1", object1);
    restAssuredRequestParams.put("YourParam2", object2);

    /**
     * Add host without http or https protocol.
     * You can also add other parameters based on your amazon service requirement.
     */
    TreeMap<String, String> awsHeaders = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    awsHeaders.put("host", "xxxxx-yyyyy-r6nvlhpscgdwms5.ap-northeast-1.es.amazonaws.com");

    AWSV4Auth aWSV4Auth = new AWSV4Auth.Builder("exampleKey", "exampleSecret", "exampleSessionToken")
                                       .regionName("xx-yy-zzz")
                                       .serviceName("es") // es - elastic search. use your service name
                                       .httpMethodName("GET") //GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc...
                                       .canonicalURI("/inventory/simple/123") //end point
                                       .queryParametes(null) //query parameters if any
                                       .awsHeaders(awsHeaders) //aws header parameters
                                       .payload(restAssuredRequestParams) // payload if any
                                       .debug() // turn on the debug mode
                                       .build();

    /* Get header calculated for request */
    Map<String, String> header = aWSV4Auth.getHeaders();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entrySet : header.entrySet()) {
        String key = entrySet.getKey();
        String value = entrySet.getValue();
        restAssuredRequest.header(key, value);

        /* Attach header in your request */
        /* Simple get request */
        //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        //httpGet.addHeader(key, value);
    }
    restAssuredRequest.body(restAssuredRequestParams);
    Response restAssuredResponse = restAssuredRequest.post(endpoint path);
    System.out.println(restAssuredResponse.asString());
    System.out.println(restAssuredResponse.getStatusCode());
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: {"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'GET

We are getting this error how to over come this please help